# Programmatically unchecking checkbox does not update angular model

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I am using the following code to programmatically uncheck a checkbox:

```
$('#someid').removeAttr('checked');
```

Here is the checkbox that is bound to an Angular model:

`<input id="someid" ng-model="model.property" type="checkbox" value="true">`

I can see that the checkbox is indeed unchecking. Why is the Angular model property not also updating (changing from true to false) and how can I obtain this desired behavior? I can update the model and have the checkbox update no problem.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you are using Angular, it's expected that you don't manipulate the DOM this way.
You have to change the angular model variable, and let Angular make the DOM changes.

Study the ToDo List example at 
[angularjs.org](https://angularjs.org/#add-some-control)

Tip: I think you really don't need jQuery anymore!

The Angular code you need:

```
$scope.model.property = false;
```

Comment: Hi .. I am facing a similar problem... but when the checkbox is initially selected, unchecking the selected checkbox doesn't update the ng-model value. It only gets fired once the box has been checked and further on. Would be of great help if there a way to capture the initial checkbox deselect.

Answer (score 1):

Your use of jQuery is breaking anglers binding to the DOM. If you need to uncheck something change the value on the model that is bound to the checkbox:

```
$scope.model = { isChecked: true };
```

bound to:

```
<input type="checkbox" ng-model="model.isChecked">
```

to "uncheck":

```
$scope.model.isChecked = false;
```

No need for jQuery.